# Trying to insert to database but nothing happens

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

I am trying to submit a form via AJAX to insert my data into database, when i press the submit button the data does not getting inserted..

```
            $invoice_number = rand(0, 99999);
        $TransactionInsert = array(
            'date'           => $this->input->post('funds_arrival_date'),
            'description'    => 'Payment against invoice #' . '<a href="/reservations/database/edit/' . $this->input->post('reservations') . '">' . $this->input->post('reservations') . '</a>' . ' via ' . '"' . $this->input->post('paid_to') . '"' . ' method',
            'product'        => $this->input->post('reservations'),
            'credit'         => $this->input->post('actual_amount'),
            'credit_cur'     => $this->input->post('currency_name'),
            'credit_cur_val' => (int)$this->input->post('currency_value'),
            'debit'          => 0,
            'parent_invoice' => $invoice_number
        );
        $this->db->insert('transactions', $TransactionInsert);
```

The jQuery

```
//Finish the process, POST AJAX...
    $('button[name=submit-transaction]').live("click", function (e) {
        var a = getTransactionValues();
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url: '/transactions/submit',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                reservations:       a.reservations,
                amount:             a.amount,
                currency_value:     a.currency_value,
                currency_name:      a.currency_name,
                actual_amount:      a.actual_amount,
                actual_remaining:   a.actual_remaining,
                funds_arrival_date: a.funds_arrival_date,
                paid_to:            a.paid_to,
                checkbox:           a.checkbox
            },
            success: function (data) {
                location.reload();
            },
        });
    });
}

    /*
*   Gathering values and getting them
*/
function getTransactionValues() {
    var o = {};
    o.parent_id           = $('.dbase_id').val();
    o.reservations        = [];
    $('#custom-headers option:selected').each(function (i, selected) {
        o.reservations[i] = $(selected).val();
    });
    o.amount              = $('input[name=amount-price]').val();
    o.currency_value      = $('input[name=currency-value]').val();
    o.currency_name       = $('.currency_appendto option:selected').html();
    o.actual_amount       = $('input[name=actual-amount]').val();
    o.actual_remaining    = $('input[name=actual-remaining]').val();
    o.funds_arrival_date  = $('input[name=funds-arrival]').val();
    o.paid_to             = $('.paidto option:selected').html();
    o.checkbox            = $('.multi-transaction:checked').map(function () {
        return this.value
    }).get();
    return o;
}
```

I don't know what is the error the page does not show me anything, and the data is not submitted to database

Comment: please check the browser's console and see if there are any JS error coming or not. If no error then see the network tab and see what is the HTTP response code for above ajax call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might be wrong but it seems like your `o.reservations = [];` part is returning an array of something, in your PHP code you are not looping it and trying to insert a bulk `$this->input->post('reservations');` you need to either loop this or access the first / second key.. whatever you need to insert like `$this->input->post('reservations')[0];` Try:

```
        $TransactionInsert = array(
        'date'           => $this->input->post('funds_arrival_date'),
        'description'    => 'Payment against invoice #' . '<a href="/reservations/database/edit/' . $this->input->post('reservations')[0] . '">' . $this->input->post('reservations')[0] . '</a>' . ' via ' . '"' . $this->input->post('paid_to') . '"' . ' method',
        'product'        => $this->input->post('reservations')[0],
        'credit'         => $this->input->post('actual_amount'),
        'credit_cur'     => $this->input->post('currency_name'),
        'credit_cur_val' => (int)$this->input->post('currency_value'),
        'debit'          => 0,
        'parent_invoice' => $invoice_number
    );
```

Answer (score 1):

I also see the base url is not correct in the ajax call in the url , I will share my ajax call that I usually use like so

I assume you are calling the transaction controller with the submit method

```
    $("#your_html_item_id").bind("click",function()
    {
        var target_url = '<?php echo(base_url()."transactions/submit") ; ?>';
        $.ajax
        (
        {
            url : target_url,
            type: "POST",
            cache: false,
            data: 
            {
                key1:       value1,
                key2:       value2,
                key3:       value3
            },
            success: function(data)
            {
                alert(1);
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
            {
                alert("error during database query");
            }
        });

    });
```

if you see a messagebox with 1 , it means ajax call was successful

Answer (score 0):

You should check your php error log and database error log.

If you don't know where to find it... you can google it :)

Comment: how can i check my error log? my page is getting reload

Comment: Are you using Linux or Windows? LAMP? OpenServer? Please specify your development environment